# I get net.createconnection is not a function using Browserify

Tags: node.js, browserify, node-mysql

I want to display some db query result on my website
Using browserify to include node modules on client side I get the error mentioned above and am stuck now:

This is my main.js

```js
const mysql = require('promise-mysql')


async function run() {
    try {
        const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            user: 'root',
            password: '',
            database: 'testdb',
            port: 3306
        })
        const result = await connection.query(
            'SELECT something FROM table1;'
        )
        await connection.end()
        return JSON.stringify(result);

    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }

}

run().then(data => {
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = data;
    console.log(data);
});
```

And this is my test websites body:
(I created the bundle.js file via $ watchify testdb_work.js -o bundle2.js -v)

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Welcome to the Client Side.</h2>

        <div class="well">

            <div id="response">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

Here is a link to the bundle.js (it is really huge):
 [bundel.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tiedurden/dpwebsite/master/bundle2.js)

I am working on macOS 10.13

Comment: Found a work arround using ajax to call a php script with the query. pm me for details